# EEA Family permit or visitor visa for my mother

Tags: uk, family

I am a German citizen living in Germany and my mother is Russian citizen living in Russia. We would like to visit UK together as tourists just for 10 days or so. Is it possible and preferable for her to get EEA family permit rather than UK visitor visa for this purpose? I think UK consulate might refuse her visitor visa because of her age, etc. She does not have any EU residence card or whatsoever. Anyway, what is the time frame for getting EEA family permit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will your visit to the UK conclude before the 29th of March? In not, any EU/EEA documentation may be moot.

Comment: @Richard it should be okay if the trip commences before 29 March, shouldn't it?

Comment: In the event of a 'no deal' brexit, it may not. While she would be in possession of a valid docs at entry, they could be deemed invalid at 11pm that day and then she'd be in the country without a valid permit. Perhaps unlikely to be spotted, but I'd exercise extreme caution on this one.

Comment: @Richard even if there's a no deal Brexit, I cannot imagine that EU visitors (including family members) will suddenly be subject to deportation at the magic hour.  Even EU citizens who have not yet applied for leave to remain will be without a valid permit, but nobody is going to get in trouble for that.

Comment: I'm not saying she'd be punished, I'm airing on the side of not recommending something that may technically be against the law.

Comment: @Richard if it's "against the law" (and I am not sure that it is; I don't know what plans exist for repealing the EEA regulations), it is only so because the legislators overlooked this case in of all the attention being (rightfully) given to people who reside in the UK under the regulations. Nobody seriously thinks that it should be against the law for someone who has been in the UK for less than three months under regulation 13 as of the appointed hour to remain. And nobody should care about technical violations of law because of legislative oversight.

Answer (score 1):

Your mother qualifies for an EEA family permit to travel with you to the UK *only if she is dependent on you.*  If she is not, then she will need a standard visitor visa.

The EEA family permit application is supposed to be decided "quickly"; it shouldn't take more than a week or two.  If you have evidence that she is dependent on you, but the decision isn't clear, it might take a bit longer.

Comment: What would be a good evidence that she is dependent on me financially if I support her with cash only so she cannot present bank statement showing my support? She is single, in old age and cannot travel on her own. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @Max it could be difficult.  I did this with my mother in law but she is registered with my wife's employer as her dependent, and we used that in the application.  I don't remember submitting evidence of actual payments (also cash).  But my wife works for a UN agency, so that might carry more weight than other such evidence.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit how your mother in law was registered with your wife's employer as her dependent? Was it in your wife's contract, payslip or she asked for some kind of certificate/document from her employer in order to present to UK consulate? Thanks.

Comment: @Max as I recall we got a letter from HR attesting to the fact.  I believe we did not submit my wife's payslips, which would have reflected a small "secondary dependent" supplement, but we might have. I do not remember whether the letter mentioned this supplement; it was a few years ago now.  As to how the registration was effected, that happened before I met my wife, but the purpose of doing so was of course to obtain the secondary dependent benefit. I don't think it's explicitly in the contract; terms and conditions are rather like civil service, so nothing is negotiable.

Comment: Is there any possibility to share this HR letter, of course, without any personal details so I have sort of a template for my HR?